# Last login Since specified time

Tags: linux

How can I check the last logins of a given user since a given time?
Tried:

```
`last -s $timeVariable $userName`
```

But that option is invalid.
I know `-t` is good to check the logins until the specified time, but I want the exact opposite. Any ideas?

Comment: the -s option works for me with 'last from util-linux 2.24'. Which version of last are you using? And how is your $timeVariable formatted?

Comment: The format is YYYYmmddHHMMSS. I have Ubuntu 14.04, but need to manage the command to work on our university server, so I need an other way